# Firebase phone authentication error on US numbers

Tags: firebase-authentication

I've added several testing phone numbers in my Firebase console, some with a +1 (US) country code, others with +30 (GR).

When I try to sign in to a GR phone number (testing or real), everything works fine. When I try a US number on the other hand, it throws this error:

```
- some : Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, 
print and inspect the error details for more information."
UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, 
NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details
for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c02ac0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3
"(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d73fc0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=500 "(null)"
UserInfo={data={length = 259, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 220a2020 7d0a7d0a },
data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 500;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "Internal error encountered.";
            reason = backendError;
        }
    );
    message = "Internal error encountered.";
    status = INTERNAL;
}}}}
```

I recently added an SMS region policy from the console, denying some countries, one of them had a +1 country code. Just to be sure, I removed them all but I still can't sign in.

Any ideas?

EDIT; I updated to 10.13.0 but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the Firebase team and apparently, it was a phone number format issue. The numbers I was testing were `+11234567` and `+11234567890`. In their words;

> Consider that it is necessary to use phone numbers that are indeed fictional, and do not already exist. Firebase Authentication does not allow you to set existing phone numbers used by real users as test numbers. One option is to use 555 prefixed numbers as US test phone numbers, for example: +1 650-555-3434.
>
> In the error logs that I noticed, the phone numbers used were +11234567890 or +11234567. These test numbers are not allowed, it is better to use phone numbers that have a prefix and that use 10 digits. Try using new test phone numbers so the verification process can be completed.

The weird this is that these test numbers worked up until 1 month ago! Anyway, thank you Firebase team and especially Oscar!!!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seemingly was resolved as our previous demo account that was failing is now functioning as it was previously.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).